# Update table row with values from same table column row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I want to update the values of column `created_at` with values of column `updated_at`, where value in the column `created_at` is **0000-00-00**.

I tried the  following query :

```
UPDATE tbl_message_types a 
SET a.created_at = (
SELECT
    c.updated_at 
FROM
    ( SELECT b.updated_at 
      FROM tbl_message_types b 
      WHERE b.created_at LIKE '%0000-00-00%' 
        AND a.id = c.id ) AS c 
    ) 
    AND a.created_at LIKE '%0000-00-00%';
```

But the result of the  query is as follows :

```
> 1054 - Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause'
> Time: 0.008s
```

How can I modify the  query ?

Answer (score 0):

Your alias is out of place, but I would phrase this update using a join:

```
UPDATE tbl_message_types a
INNER JOIN UPDATE tbl_message_types b
    ON a.id = b.id AND
       COALESCE(b.created_at, '0000-00-00') != '0000-00-00'
WHERE COALESCE(a.created_at, '0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00';
```

Note that it is not clear how you ended up with datetime values of `0000-00-00` in your table.  I am treating `NULL` the same way in my answer, though you may remove the call to `COALESCE` if you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in much simplified way.. without any join gimmicks; Why should you insist on a single query..? Do the select First, and update next. Try this..

```
     select 

        value1 from tableName 

        where columnX like '%someThing%' and columnY = 'SomeValue' as value11;

     update sametableName set someColumn= value11

         where....
```